Uncaught (in promise) Error Showing while sending data response in node js and map function showing error in react
Here is the node js
getting error in promise
import express from "express";

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/jokes', (req ,res) => {
  const jokes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Why don\'t scientists trust atoms?',
      content: 'Because they make up everything!'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Did you hear about the mathematician who\'s afraid of negative numbers?',
      content: 'He\'ll stop at nothing to avoid them!'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Why did the scarecrow win an award?',
      content: 'Because he was outstanding in his field!'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Why don\'t skeletons fight each other?',
      content: 'They don\'t have the guts!'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: 'What do you call fake spaghetti?',
      content: 'An impasta!'
    }
  ];

      res.send(jokes);        
    }); 


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Error that i am getting
here is react code
Tried using map function in react file and i am getting uncaught TypeError: jokes.map is not a function
import  { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import React from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css'
function App() {
  const [jokes, setJokes] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3000/jokes')
   .then((response) =>{
    setJokes(response.data)
   })
   .catch((error) =>{
    setJokes(error)
   })
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <>
     <h1>Fullstack</h1>
      <p>JOKES : {jokes.length}</p>
      
      {
        jokes.map((joke,index) =>{
            <div key={joke.id} >
              <h3>{joke.title}</h3>
              <h3>{joke.title}</h3>
            </div>
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}
export default App


error in frontend 
i have tried sending data using app.send and app.json both but it stil showing Uncaught (in promise)  in console
also i wont able to map it in react error says jokes.map is not a function

httpstatus is 200 ... but then there's the code 403 ... a user Auth error ... there's no auth involved in the code you posted

i have only two files one for nodejs and other one for react and i have posted all the code that i have written .There is  no auth code that i have written

That just isn't possible. The error message you posted references a POST request to /web_page_mark as being the source of the error. Something you are running is attempting to hit that path and getting the 403. As for your actual error, you are getting response.data back as an object that doesn't have a map method. You should check in your code that handles the axios response to avoid calling the state setter if you don't get back the data type you expect.

You are getting this error because jokes is undefined, there are several reasons why that might be happening. Since you asked for a frontend solution for this question, one way to avoid getting this response irrespective of whether jokes is defined or not is to use the optional chaining operation ?.  So do something like this instead to avoid getting this kind of error.
{
  jokes?.map((joke,index) =>{
    <div key={joke?.id} >
      <h3>{joke?.title}</h3>
      <h3>{joke?.title}</h3>
    </div>
  })
}

What this operator ? does is tell js to only call map if jokes is defined and only read the values title, id if joke is defined.
You might need to look into your backend code to confirm if you are getting a valid response for the endpoint you are calling.

Not the DV, but this is bad advice: you are telling the OP to wallpaper over a bug in their logic.

For some reason your server is declining your request. As a result jokes is undefined.
There is nothing in your backend code that should be causing this. Have you tried using a different port for your backend?

This does not answer the question.
